# HTMLUNIT doesnt work well

Tags: java, eclipse, htmlunit

I downloaded all necessary jars and ran this test program :

```
public void getElements() throws Exception {
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://www.facebook.com/");
final HtmlDivision div = page.getHtmlElementById("_li");
//final HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByName("anchor_name");

webClient.closeAllWindows();
```

}
but it exits every time due to an error:
דצמ 09, 2014

```
2:04:10 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify

WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.

דצמ 09, 2014 2:04:11 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify

WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.

Exception in thread "main" com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[*] attributeName=[id] attributeValue=[_li]

    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getElementById(HtmlPage.java:1729)

    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getHtmlElementById(HtmlPage.java:1679)

    at DmozSpider.main(DmozSpider.java:16)
```

Comment: Is DmozSpider your own class? Which line is line 16?

Comment: the class - i created. I was mistaken in my qeustion and updated it now. line 16 is final HtmlDivision div = page.getHtmlElementById("_li");

Comment: You can always construct the httprequest and login that way

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
page.getHtmlElementById("_li");
```

the code throws an `ElementNotFoundException` because the DOM doesn't have any XML element with the id "_li". As the [Javadoc of ElementNotFoundException](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/ElementNotFoundException.html) states:

> An exception that is thrown when a specified XML element cannot be found in the DOM model.

If you are looking to select a div tag with `class="_li"`, then you should use

```
page.getByXPath("//div[@class='_li']");
```

Comment: there is id _li and i also tried with different id's and it gives me the same problem

Comment: `class` and `id` are different. Edited the answer.

Comment: it still doesnt work.
i copied examples from here : http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2011/05/16/htmlunit-a-quick-introduction/
and it also didnt work

Comment: I don't see any `<div class=...>` example there.

Comment: I know, but i took the xpath example from there